# Footer scaling with scalebox

Tags: beamer, header-footer, pstricks, scaling

I use a `pspicture` to draw a electric diagram in one of my slides with beamer, and I've got a pause-command within the `pspicture` (to make thing appear).

I use `\scalebox` to make my picture enter the slide without exceeding.

When I compile, I see my footer (I use the theme of my university) scaling with the pspicture.

It's also the same using `\psscalebox`.

What can I do?
Is there a special command to put in the definition of the theme?
Can somebody help me?

EDIT :
I made an example :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,here}
\usepackage{cancel}
\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\red}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % Delete Navigation Buttons
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Here is my diagram}
\begin{center}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1.5, 0)(10, 6.5)
\psscalebox{0.65}{  
    \pnode(-1.5, 5){E}
    \pnode(-1.5, 6.5){F}
    \pnode(-1.5, 8){G}
    \pnode(-1.5, 8.5){H}

    \pnode(0, 0){A}
    \pnode(0, 5){B}
    \pnode(0, 6.5){C}
    \pnode(0, 8){D}
    \pnode(0, 8.5){I}
    \pnode(0, 10){L}

    \pnode(2.5, 8.5){K}
    \pnode(2.5, 5){J}

    \pnode(4, 5.5){A1}
    \pnode(4, 3.5){B1}
    \pnode(4, 1.5){C1}

    \pnode(4.5, 10){M}
    \pnode(4.5, 9){W}

    \pnode(6, 8){Y}
    \pnode(6, 6){X}
    \pnode(6, 5.5){P}
    \pnode(6, 4.5){E1}
    \pnode(6, 2.5){D1}

    \pnode(7, 8.5){N}
    \pnode(7, 8){O}
    \pnode(7, 2.5){G1}
    \pnode(7, 0){H1}

    \pnode(7.5, 4.5){F1}

    \pnode(8, 8){Z}
    \pnode(8, 6){Q}
    \pnode(8, 3.5){I1}
    \pnode(8, 2.5){J1}

    \pnode(10, 6){R}
    \pnode(10, 1.5){K1}

    \pnode(12, 6){S}
    \pnode(12, 0){L1}

    \pnode(13.5, 6){T}
    \pnode(13.5, 0.5){U}
    \pnode(13.5, 0){V}

    %--------------
    \wire[arrows=-*](A)(B)
    \cell(B)(C){}
    \cell(C)(D){}
    \cell(E)(F){}
    \cell(F)(G){}
    \wire(B)(E)
    \wire(G)(H)
    \wire(H)(I)
    \wire[arrows=-*](D)(I)
    \diode[arrows=-*, labeloffset=0.5](I)(K){1N4001}
    \wire(B)(J)
    \multidipole(K)(J)
    \battery[labeloffset=0.9]{$\SI{1.2}{\volt}$}
    \battery[labeloffset=0.9]{$\SI{1.2}{\volt}$}
    {}
    \wire(I)(L)
    \wire(L)(M)
    \transistor[TRot=-90, transistortype=PNP, transistorinvert=true, transistorcircle=false](W){emitter}{collecteur}
    \wire(TBaseNode)(M)
    \wire(emitter)(N)
    \wire(collecteur)(K)
    \wire[arrows=-*](N)(O)
    \wire(Y)(Z)
    {\only<1>{\resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag, labeloffset=0.7](X)(Y){${\SI{1}{\kilo\ohm}}$}}}

    \coil[dipolestyle=curved, labeloffset=1, arrows=-*](Z)(Q){$\SI{470}{\micro\henry}$} 
    \wire[arrows=-*](X)(P)
    \wire[arrows=-*](P)(E1)
    \wire(P)(A1)
    \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag, labeloffset=-0.8, arrows=-*](A1)(B1){$\SI{4,7}{\kilo\ohm}$}
    \psline(B1)(C1)(K1)
    \transistor[transistorcircle=false](5.5, 3.5){emitter}{collecteur}
    \wire(TBaseNode)(B1)
    \wire(emitter)(D1)
    \wire(collecteur)(E1)
    \psline(D1)(J1)(I1)
    \transistor[transistorcircle=false](F1){emitter}{collecteur}
    \wire(TBaseNode)(E1)
    \wire(emitter)(I1)
    \wire(collecteur)(Q)
    \wire[arrows=-*](Q)(R)
    \only<1>{\multidipole(R)(K1)
    \capacitor[dipolestyle=chemical, labeloffset=-1]{$\SI{0.012}{\micro\farad}$}
    \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag, labeloffset=-0.8]{$\SI{1}{\kilo\ohm}$}
    {}}
    \diode[arrows=-*, labeloffset=0.5](R)(S){1N4001}
    {\only<1>{\capacitor[dipolestyle=chemical, labeloffset=-1, arrows=-*](S)(L1){$\SI{1}{\milli\farad}$}}}
    \wire(S)(T)
    \multidipole(T)(U)
    \LED{}
    \LED{}
    \LED{}
    \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag, labeloffset=0.7]{$\SI{220}{\ohm}$}
    {}
    \wire(U)(V)
    \wire(V)(A)
    \wire[arrows=*-*](H1)(G1)

\pause

    \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag, labeloffset=0.7](X)(Y){\cancel{${\SI{1}{\kilo\ohm}}$}}
    \multidipole(R)(K1)
    \capacitor[dipolestyle=chemical, labeloffset=-1]{\cancel{$\SI{0.012}{\micro\farad}$}}
    \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag, labeloffset=-0.8]{\cancel{$\SI{1}{\kilo\ohm}$}}
    {}
    \capacitor[dipolestyle=chemical, labeloffset=-1, arrows=-*](S)(L1){\cancel{$\SI{1}{\milli\farad}$}}
     \rput(5.3, 6.6){{\color{red}\sffamily ${\SI{47}{\ohm}}$}}
     \rput(8.9, 4.5){\color{red}\sffamily {$\SI{1}{\micro\farad}$}}
     \rput(9.1, 2.2){\color{red}\sffamily {$\SI{5.6}{\kilo\ohm}$}}
     \rput(11, 2.6){\color{red}\sffamily {$\SI{47}{\milli\farad}$}}
     }
\end{pspicture}

\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You see? The footer on the first slide scales. What happens?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I also [marked your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) with backticks.

Comment: Please provide the minimal dummy code yet compilable with which we can work.

Comment: I've made a simple example...
Hope it'll clear this out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use it this way:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

[...]    

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Here is my diagram}

\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1.5, 0)(10, 6.5)
\psscalebox{0.65}{%  
    \pnode(-1.5, 5){E}
    \pnode(-1.5, 6.5){F}
[...]
    \wire[arrows=*-*](H1)(G1)%%  end first \psscalebox
}
\pause

\psscalebox{0.65}{%
    \resistor[dipolestyle=zigzag, labeloffset=0.7](X)(Y){\cancel{${\SI{1}{\kilo\ohm}}$}}
    \multidipole(R)(K1)

[...]

     \rput(9.1, 2.2){\color{red}\sffamily {$\SI{5.6}{\kilo\ohm}$}}
     \rput(11, 2.6){\color{red}\sffamily {$\SI{47}{\milli\farad}$}}%
     }%%%%%%   another \psscalebox
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For every slide an own `\psscalebox`